# Why will ImageView.StartAnimating not animate on the Main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, animation, xamarin.ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to animate an series of icon images in a TableView cell and I'm unable to get ImageView.StartAnimating to work. The TableView is in a UITableViewController and there's a TableViewDataSource file where the TableView contents are set up.

In my TableViewDataSource I set up the array of PNGs and configure various animation preferences.

```
UIImage image0 = GetImage("Images/image_at_0_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage image45 = GetImage("Images/image_at_45_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage image90 = GetImage("Images/image_at_90_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage image135 = GetImage("Images/image_at_135_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage[] images = new UIImage[] { image0, image135, image90, image45 };

cell.ImageView.AnimationImages = images;
cell.ImageView.AnimationDuration = 0.5;
cell.ImageView.AnimationRepeatCount = 0;
cell.ImageView.Image = image0;

// cell.ImageView.StartAnimating(); // If called here images will animate
```

If I call StartAnimating in the TableViewDataSource (commented out in the above example) the images animate in sequence.

But it's in my UITableViewController where I want the images to animate in response to a certain event being fired.

In ViewWillAppear I get a reference to the specific cell's ImageView

```
UITableViewCell cell = TableView.CellAt(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 2));
imagetoAnimate = (UIImageView)cell.ContentView.ViewWithTag(ICON_TAG);
```

Then when the event is raised I call StartAnimating on the main thread (I added the Console.WriteLines just to confirm that the code inside the InvokeOnMainThread block is indeed executing on the main thread - it is. Also, all the other code inside the InvokeOnMainThread block was there previously.)

```
private void Application_Event()
{      
    Console.WriteLine("Running on Thread ID {0}. Is Main thread? {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, NSThread.IsMain); // Returns false

    InvokeOnMainThread(delegate 
    { 

        Console.WriteLine("Running on Thread ID {0}. Is Main thread? {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, NSThread.IsMain); // Returns true

        imageToAnimate.StartAnimating(); // If called here images don't animate
        UpdateCount();
        UpdateStatus(); 
    });
}
```

It's got to be something simple that I'm missing. Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1**

The UpdateCount and UpdateStatus methods contain TableView.ReloadData statements which appear to be interfering with ImageView.StartAnimating (commenting out both lines allows the animation to proceed).

Has anyone ever heard of this type of thing happening before?

**UPDATE #2**

Moving the code block that sets ImageView.AnimationImages out of the GetCell method and into the UITableViewController solves the issue.

```
UIImage image0 = GetImage("Images/image_at_0_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage image45 = GetImage("Images/image_at_45_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage image90 = GetImage("Images/image_at_90_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage image135 = GetImage("Images/image_at_135_degrees@2x.png");
UIImage[] images = new UIImage[] { image0, image135, image90, image45 };

cell.ImageView.AnimationImages = images;
cell.ImageView.AnimationDuration = 0.5;
cell.ImageView.AnimationRepeatCount = 0;
cell.ImageView.Image = image0;
```

When this is done and the TableView.ReloadData statements are uncommented the animation proceeds normally when ImageView.StartAnimating is called.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint where you're calling `imageToAnimate.StartAnimating()`, it is non-null and has all the appropriate values such as `AnimationImages` filled out, right?

Comment: Yes, imageToAnimate is not null, AnimationImages has the four images in it and isAnimating = false (isAnimating flips to true when StartAnimating called).

Comment: Is `GetCell` getting called or the table view reloading immediately after?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers See the UPDATE section above - the two methods called after imageToAnimate.StartAnimating contain TableView.ReloadData statements at their respective ends (commenting out these statements lets the animation proceed). There is no call to GetCell anywhere in the UITableViewController code.

Comment: `GetCell` is where your `UITableViewSource` returns a cell to be displayed, can you post that code?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers My mistake re GetCell. I can't post the entire section of code but I can tell you that the first code example above (where AnimationImages is set) is in the GetCell method. If I were take this to the next step, I would say the TableView.ReloadData call resets the ImageView, setting it's main image back to the starting image and flipping the bit on StartAnimating - Correct? If so, a solution might be to move that piece of code out of GetCell and put it in the UITableViewController right after I get the reference to the specific cell's ImageView.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Moving the ImageView configuration code out of GetCell worked (see Update #2 above). If you put a brief answer outlining the solution I'll accept so you can get the credit for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `UITableView.ReloadData` will reload all the of the cells, and `GetCell` will get called again on your table view source.

This will probably stop the animation from occurring.